# Declension of proper name adjectives?

Tags: грамматика, падежи, прилагательные, склонение

Is there a table or list of rules on how to write the proper name (possessive?) adjective of a word, based on case as well?

For example,

*Пашины* родители

*Пашиным* родителям

*Пашиной* матери

*Юрины* дни рождения

*Юриному* отцу

*Юрин**Ы**ми* руками

и.т.д...

Comment: yes, they're called possessive, here're **[Google search results](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&source=hp&ei=NeFyWoqhJYLLwAL72bIQ&q=таблица+склонения+притяжательных+прилагательных)** with a host of resources, all in Russian though

Comment: To form such an adjective, replace the final -а or -я of the name with -ин: Паша - Пашин, Галя - Галин. Declension rules are the same as any hard-stem adjective e.g. новый: нового - Пашиного, новому -Пашиному, etc except for the singular nominative which doesn't have -ый: новый - Пашин.

Comment: Oh, and the plural nominative is also a bit exceptional: -ы instead of -ые: новые - Пашины

Comment: Obviously, as for all Russian adjectives, the inanimate accusative matches the nominative in both singular and plural.

Comment: Not sure why this question was marked as "too broad". It sounds quite specific to me.